# How to calculate the overall value of the row?

Tags: mysql, sql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

[image]

The results I want

[image]

Please Help Me, Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `group by with rollup` along with `ifnull`:

```
select ifnull(customer, 'Total') customer, sum(qty)
from yourtable
group by customer 
with rollup
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0650a/1)

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it this way (syntax as per SQL Server):

```
select Customer,sum(Qty)
from whatevertable
group by Customer
Union
select 'Total' as Customer,sum(Qty)
from whatevertable
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pentaho Kettle (PDI): Drag two hops from a step, and make sure you choose 'Copy'. One of the output streams can be used to aggregate on Customer level, the other one can be used to get a Total aggregation. Then use an 'Append streams' step.